# How do I cat multi-line content to a file in a systemd unit file?

Tags: systemd

I am trying to write a file to disk as part of the `ExecStartPre` command of a systemd unit file.

This is what I am using:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service

[Service]
Restart=always
StartLimitInterval=0
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/cat <<EOFDefaults > /tmp/test
option1=value1
option2=value2
EOFDefaults

ExecStart=/run/some/command
```

Since that's a multi-line command, I get the following error when testing it with `systemd-analyze verify myservice.service`.

So, I tried to escape the multi-lines:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service

[Service]
Restart=always
StartLimitInterval=0
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/cat <<EOFDefaults > /tmp/test \
option1=value1 \
option2=value2 \
EOFDefaults

ExecStart=/run/some/command
```

When testing the unit file, I get the following error: `Invalid escape sequences in command line:`

How does one use cat to write multi-line content to a file as part of a systemd unit file command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't.
See the documentation section on [Command lines](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines):

> This syntax is intended to be very similar to shell syntax, but only the meta-characters and expansions described in the following paragraphs are understood. Specifically, redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not supported.

You might be able to do this by calling a shell first with something like:

```
    ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/cat <<EOFDefaults > /tmp/test \
    option1=value1 \
    option2=value2 \
    EOFDefaults'
```

However it becomes cluttered really fast.

What I would do, is to put this in a separate shell script and call that from the service definition. In general is is best to keep the service definition as clear as possible.

Comment: Tried calling a shell from `ExecStarPre`, but it didn't work. Ended up using a shell script.

Comment: @F21 It also needs an `\n` before each trailing `\ `, because otherwise the lines are just concatenated into one line. Also consider removing the extraneous space before the trailing `\ `, which will otherwise end up in the here-doc and might become a hard-to-find bug if it causes problems.